# Как перенести из дампа MySQL в локальную базу (SQLite или SQL Compact)

Tags: c#, sql

Есть MySQL Dump - http://pastebin.com/ez4hmL9k
Как можно выполнить этот запрос, чтобы добавилась таблица в какую-нибудь локальную БД.

Возникают ошибки при выполнении запроса, то не понимает тип "int", то "AUTO_INCREMENT".

Как быть?

Answer (score 2):

На сайте SQLite-а есть линуксовый [шеллскрипт](https://gist.github.com/943776), который преобразует MySQL-вский дамп к нужному виду.

Если с ним будут проблемы - загляните в [этот раздел](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools) на официальном сайте SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Стандарт ANSI SQL так или иначе поддерживают все СУБД. А вот расширенный SQL в каждой из них реализован по-разному. Это касается и функций, и атрибутов, и всего прочего. Поэтому вам нужно найти инструмент конвертации или адаптировать полученный файл перед загрузкой самостоятельно.

Comment: А вы случаем не знаете такой инструмент?

Comment: Хорошие ссылки для SQLite привёл @Nofate. В своё время я использовал http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Converting_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL для конвертации из MySQL в PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Читать из файла запросики и приводить их к виду понятному для SQLite, Compact

Comment: Там очень большие запросы я так буду очень долго приводить их к виду. Учитывая даже что открывая такой файл всё виснит